# Asterisk Module to dump queue stats

Tags: c, asterisk

Can someone provide me with code or information on how to write a asterisk module which will dump queue statistics to a file. 
Please provide links which have good documentation on how to do this.

I have followed [this code](http://blog.russellbryant.net/2008/06/19/how-to-write-an-asterisk-module-part-1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no need do such module.

Queue statistics already dumped as events into queue_log.

You can re-organzied that by external program.

If you need status of queue, you cna use something like that

```
asterisk -rx "queue show"
```

And parse that for you need using perl or bash script.